# c# WinForm - how asking for credential with a Dialog form?

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the better way for asking for username and password in c#?

I need them to pass in a `DirectoryContext` Class call.

I need something like Get-Credential in Powershell, to store username and password in a variable.

Googling for it I found some interesting Class for this job, but there isn't a built in class in framework 4.0 ( exemple: `var cred = new credentialDialog()`?

Strong Security is an optional, need just mask the input password field.

Thank you all

Comment: Why not create your own? It's pretty simple.

Comment: @Ash: Yes is a solution.. But if exist a class why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: It takes 5 minutes to design and implement a form that does what you need ;)

Comment: there is a standardized dialog for this (see my answer below). Why create something custom when you can use the built in dialog with the standard Windows UI.  The application will look more integrated with the OS if it uses the OS's dialogs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PInvoke one of these APIs based on your OS

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375177.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375178.aspx

Or use this http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/archive/2005/11/21/usercredentialsdialog.aspx that wraps the API call in a slightly more friendly managed library.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [CredUIPromptForCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375177.aspx) WinAPI function (which generates the standard authentication window as below). See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304203117/https://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/usercredentialsdialog) to use it with C# (or [here](http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=CredUIPromptForCredentials&namespace=%5BAll%5D)).

[image]