# how to make WebClient prompt for credentials

Tags: wcf, webclient

so I have this code, which works:

```
    var netCred = new NetworkCredential { UserName = "user1", Password = @"pass1" };
    WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
    proxy.Credentials = netCred;

    //Method 1 - Newtonsoft.Json


        string serviceURL =
           string.Format("https://sourcesite.com/api/external/v1/Snapshot-Accrual?isConfirmed="
            + Confirmed.ToString() + "&sinceDate=" + String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", SinceDate);
        data = proxy.DownloadData(serviceURL);
        jsonString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

        ac1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SnapshotAccruals>(jsonString);
```

Now if I only knew how to prompt for credentials instead of hard-coding them, I'd be set. I know that if I paste the serviceURL directly in the browser, it will ask me for credentials. If I omit them in the code I get (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: What kind of application is the client that contains the example code above?  Is it a console application, a WinForms client, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look how the browser works using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and you will see that when you paste the URL into the browser the server returns a 401 which then prompts the browser to show the auth dialog.

If you know you will always need credentials then you should prompt before your API call. If you dont know then you will need to try first and check the response for 401 and then prompt

Comment: Thanks. Is there a standard way to ask for credentials in WinForms or do i have to write my own dialog box?

Comment: it may be easier to create your own OR you can try using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986862/c-sharp-winform-how-asking-for-credential-with-a-dialog-form